# Recursive permutation without loops or itertools

Tags: python, recursion, permutation, backtracking

Searched the entire web for a solution, couldn't find anything. 
Need some help figuring out the algorithm, getting all the permutations with repetitions. 
I'm not allowed to use loops or any other helper libraries.

```
def func(num):
    # The solution
```

The `num`, represents the number of each node length.

For example, if `num=1`, the solution would be `['a', 'b', 'c']` 
or if `num=2`, then `['aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ba', 'bb', 'bc', 'ca', 'cb', 'cc']`, etc

 Thank you

Comment: Here is a big hint: don't just pass `num` as an argument to your recursive function. Also pass the list of items to pick from.

Comment: Then, try to work out a recursive formula. A permutation of size `num` consists in a first element followed by a permutation of size `num-1`. Can you find a way to generate all permutations of size `num`, if your recursive call allows you to generate lists of permutations of size `num-1`?

Comment: Also, I don't know what your search of "the entire web" consisted in, but I googled "recursive function permutations" and the first twenty results all contain the code you're looking for. However, I strongly advise not googling it, and trying to work it out for yourself.

Comment: Also I suggest calling your function `permutations` or `perms` or something more explicit than `func`

Comment: PS: Although you don't want to use itertools to solve the problem, you'll need to test your function to make sure it works correctly, and comparing its output to the output of itertools.permutations is a good way to do that. The permutations might not be listed in the same order, so I suggest comparing using `sorted`: `if sorted(perms(sequence, num)) == sorted(itertools.permutations(sequence, num)): print('ok') else: print('not ok')`

Comment: I tried to work on it, and figure it out, that's why I'm here :) I did a search just like what you said, but it didn't show the solution I need

Comment: check out [tag:recursive-backtracking].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive generator function:

```
vals = ['a', 'b', 'c']
def combos(d, n, c = ''):
   if len(c) == n:
       yield c
   else:
       def _range(x=0):
          if x < len(d):
              yield from combos(d, n, c=c+d[x])
              yield from _range(x+1)
       yield from _range()

print([*combos(vals, 2)])
```

Output:

```
['aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ba', 'bb', 'bc', 'ca', 'cb', 'cc']
```

Answer (score 1):

We can write `combinations` that accepts any iterable, `t`, to compute fixed-length combinations of any integer size, `n` -

```py
def combinations(t, n):
  if n <= 0:
    yield ()
  elif not t:
    return
  else:
    for x in combinations(t, n - 1):
      yield (t[0], *x)
    yield from combinations(t[1:], n)
```

Any iterable can be used as input. Combinations treats `"abc"` equivalent to `["a", "b", "c"]` in this case -

```py
for x in combinations("abc", 2):
  print(x)
```

```py
('a', 'a')
('a', 'b')
('a', 'c')
('b', 'b')
('b', 'c')
('c', 'c')
```

It works for all positive integer values of `n` -

```py
for x in combinations("abc", 1):
  print(x)
```

```py
('a',)
('b',)
('c',)
```

And produces an empty output when `n = 0` or `n < 0` -

```py
for x in combinations("abc", 0):
  print(x)
```

```py
()
```

Using a tuple as the accumulator, `combinations` is not limited to string-based combinations only. The caller can easily join the tuple to create two-char strings, if desired -

```py
for x in combinations("abc", 2):
  print("".join(x))
```

```
aa
ab
ac
bb
bc
cc
```

Answer (score -1):

The functions func(n) and func1(list1,list2) will generate the permutations. Function func1 will multiply pairs n times.  When n=1 , (a,b,c). Then when n=2, (a,b,c) x (a,b,c). When n=3, (a,b,c) ^ 3 .

```py
input = ['a','b','c']
input2 = input
output = [ ]

def func(t):
        global input
        global input2
        global output
        if t==1:
            print(input)    
        if t>1:
             func1(0,0)
             input=output 
             output=[]
             func(t-1)

def func1(x,y):
        global input
        global input2
        global output
        if y<len(input):
           output.append(input2[x]+input[y])
           func1(x,y+1)    
        if y+1>len(input) and x+1<len(input2):
           func1(x+1,0)    
        return input[x]

func(2)
```

Displaying the output when func(2):

```sh
['aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ba', 'bb', 'bc', 'ca', 'cb', 'cc']
```

Comment: Welcome to the community. It would be good to provide an actual code with example instead of a pseudo code.

Comment: Hi, this is the actual code. But how can i type it in python? The first letters got uppercase automatically.

Comment: You can use the code sample button from the formatting toolbar (5th position) and manually lowercase the required variables/functions. Another way is to click on edit where you are able to see a properly formatted python code and you'd be able to see the source.

Comment: I'm sorry. I did not know how to type the code.  I think this is the right way.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).